# Jmeter gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError beyond 2000 threads, even after increasing the heap size to maximum

Tags: java, jmeter, out-of-memory, heap-size

I am running load test on my target using concurrency thread group. I have also increased the heap size to 6GB. Now when I run the script, beyond 2000 threads it gives

```java
Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached. See log file for details.
```

I tried varying the heap size from 512MB to 8GB but every time it cannot go beyond 2000 threads

Answer (score 4):

The error means that the underlying operating system has failed to create a new thread so you need to tweak the operating system in order to allow creating more threads for the process/current user.

- Windows: [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/)
- Linux: [How to Set Limits on User Running Processes in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/set-limits-on-user-processes-using-ulimit-in-linux/)

If you don't have administrator/root access to the machine where JMeter is running you will have to go for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) as you will not be able to overcome the OS limit on the number of processes. Amending JMeter's HEAP will not help.

Comment: can you tell me how to push the limit on Mac?

Comment: http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2010/01/19/mac-os-x-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to overcome this problem.

1- You should use distributed testing for larger threads, the recommended solution.

2- You need to adjust the ramp up period accordingly to accommodate larger thread numbers.